# How to update pivot table whose source data gets updated by a macros?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dashboard, pivot-chart

I have a dashboard by pivot charts. The source data gets updated via a macros. However, when i refresh data for the pivot tables, the source data table gets reduced to the headers of the source file? Is there a way I can refresh these pivot tables without having to select the source data every time I update the source sheet by running the macros ?

Comment: Do you have access to update the macros?

Comment: The code would vary based on how the source file was set up (in Excel on a worksheet with nothing else, in a table on a sheet, on the same sheet as other data, etc.).  It sounds like your existing code may be attempting to recreate the pivot table instead of refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to refresh your pivot table, you could add a new sub for only that reason.  Here is an example:

```
Sub RefreshPivotTable()

Dim ws As Worksheet 'Sheet containing the pivot table
Dim rng As Range 'top left cell of the pivot table
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set ws = Worksheets("Pivot Cohort")
Set rng = ws.Range("G1")
Set pt = rng.PivotTable

'~~> Refresh only this pivot table
pt.RefreshTable

'~~> Or Refresh all tables and queries in the active workbook
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'~~> Clear the variables from memory
Set ws = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set pt = Nothing

End Sub
```